# Powering two devices with a Li-Ion battery

Tags: raspberry-pi, lithium-ion

I have a Li-Ion battery powered device that can be plugged in a computer for charging purposes as well as for data transfer.

What I would like to do is have data transferred to the device via a Raspberry Pi as well as have the device’s power shared with the Pi. Would this be considered safe as the Pi could try charging the device that it’s sharing a battery with?

Here is a diagram that I have drawn:
[image: diagram]

Answer (score 0):

I see couple of issues:

Are you powering the Pi Zero **bypassing the on board regulator**?
3.7 V can damage the processor and on board chips which run at 3.3 V

If you are **not bypassing-->** the on board regulator will have a drop out voltage and may fail to provide you the 3.3 V necessary for normal operation of the Pi .

Comment: I'm bypassing the regulation I assume by powering the Pi from the GPIO pins

Comment: GPIO pin of the device? your diagram in the question suggests otherwise

Comment: What is the device? If the battery is internal then powering an external device by connecting directly to it is quite dangerous, particularly if they share a common data connection. Powering the Pi with a Lipo battery must be done through the 5V input. It should work down to ~3.4V which is ~90% of the battery's capacity.